# Django can't find package even though in virtualenv

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, importerror, django-cms

I'm coming into an inherited Django project, so I can't say how it was originally set up. However, `pip freeze` tells me that django-cms is installed in the virtualenv:

```
(demo)$ pip freeze
...
django-cms==3.3.0
...
```

So why when I do anything with, `manage.py`, do I get an error saying it's not available?

(demo)$

```
 ./manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/iscape/sites/demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/iscape/sites/demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/iscape/sites/demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/iscape/sites/demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/iscape/sites/demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named cms
```

I can also confirm that `VIRTUAL_ENV` has the correct value in the "activate" script.  It's like `pip` knows what's installed, but Django doesn't.

This is Django1.8, btw, though I don't know how much of a factor that is.

Any ideas? I'm getting nothing out of the stack trace and don't know where else to look.

Comment: Did you move the folder with the virtual environment at all?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you can `import cms` from a `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: I did not move the folder with the virtual environment. And unfortunately I can't get a `manage.py` shell. That's what yields the error above (even just `./manage.py --help` causes the error)